# ASP.Net Core StackExchangeRedis not connecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis

I am trying to setup Redis caching in my web API.

I first ran a Docker container to test this:

```bash
docker run --name redis -d -p 127.0.0.1:56379:6379 redis:7 redis-server --loglevel debug
```

The Redis server accepts connections:

```bash
$ ./redis-bash-cli -p 56379 PING
PONG
```

I have this in my `appsettings.json`:

```json
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Redis": "redis://localhost:56379"
    }
```

I set up the cache like this:

```cs
var conf = builder.Configuration;
if(conf.GetConnectionString("Redis") is string redisConnStr) {
    builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(opts => {
        opts.Configuration = redisConnStr;
        opts.InstanceName = "MyService";
    });
} else {
    builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
}
```

When I inject `IDistributedCache`, I get it injected fine, but then I try to access it:

```cs
if(await _cache.GetAsync(cacheKey, ct) is byte[] bytes) {
  // work with the data
}
```

no connection is ever made. The log of the Redis server looks like this:

```
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:01.134 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:06.147 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:11.163 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:16.174 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:21.187 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:26.200 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:31.212 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:36.224 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:41.236 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:46.248 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:51.261 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:45:56.274 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:46:01.287 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:46:06.299 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
1:M 19 Jan 2024 11:46:11.312 . 0 clients connected (0 replicas), 890600 bytes in use
```

What am I missing? Is the Connection String wrong?

Comment: if your in development environment I suggest you to use `WindowsService` version of `Redis`. Works much better on windows. https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases

Comment: @RezaNoei while I acknowledge the convenience of redis-64, I can't in good conscience recommend it these days; honestly, I think OP's approach using docker is fine here, and will give a far more up-to-date and consistent redis experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackExchange.Redis does not (to date) support the uri format for endpoints (unless I blinked and missed a merge); try instead:

```json
   "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Redis": "localhost:56379"
    }
```

i.e. using a valid StackExchange.Redis configuration string; more information on the format is [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html)

Note that if port 56379 is behind TLS, you should add `,ssl=true`; you may also need `,sslHost=yourHostHere` (for whatever host is named on the cert)